# Edit history not always visible?

Tags: support

For example [Edges of what kind of graph may not be partitioned as triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174710/edges-of-what-kind-of-graph-may-not-be-partitioned-as-triangles)

I'm pretty sure the question-text has changed at least once (some examples were removed), but I can't see any edit history. Why??

Comment: Hrm, it seem that what happened is that the site sometimes has trouble serving the MathJAX (or maybe my browser has trouble always rendering it.) After reloading the page a couple of times, the examples appeared again...

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Thanks for the explanation. So edits in rapid succession could also have the same effect that I saw... The issue of lumping in edit history has been discussed before I see: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/revision-history-seems-to-lump-together-separate-edits So if nothing else is going on there, this is a duplicate question.

Comment: There is actually something strange going on, but it might not be reproducible by anyone else, even though it's 100% reproducible for me. If I go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174710/edges-of-what-kind-of-graph-may-not-be-partitioned-as-triangles#comment2392995_1174710 (this is a comment link) *by clicking the item from my user profile -> activities* then MathJAX flashes briefly the examples in the question and then they disappear! However if I follow that exact same link by pasting it into the browser address bar it works just fine, MathJAX included, i.e. it doesn't disappear.

Comment: [Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/A8cXO4F) of what I always see (after the brief flash) when I go that page following the link from my profile->activities.

Comment: I've been having a similar problem. I flagged a post for moderator attention, saying that OP had vandalized his own question by removing all the equations; when I went back to have a look at the question, all the math was there, and the edit history showed it had never been removed. It has happened a couple of times since; a page has no math on it, then I reload, and the math is there.

Comment: Now, after that question has received an answer, then I follow the link to it from my profile it shows up ok, i.e. MathJAX doesn't disappear... Go figure!